# How to deal with @OneToMany association and pagination in Hibernate JPA?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, pagination

I am using Hibernate JPA 2.1 version. In one of the entity am using @OneToMany association which is associated to another entity with Collection(Set).

```
Person Entity
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "**phone**", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Phone> phone;
```

and in another entity am using @ManyToOne association as below:

```
Phone entity
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "PHONE_ID", nullable = false)
        private Phone **phone**;
```

Now the phone is related to another entity called Operator, which has @ManyToOne association from Phone entity as below.

```
Operator entity
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "OPERATOR_ID", referencedColumnName = "OPERATOR_ID", nullable = false)
        private Operator operator;
```

These 3 are the entities am using.

Now I want to search operator name so that particular searched Person record associated with that particular operator should come. Used below query.

```
@Query(value =  "select aud from Person person "
            + "inner join person.phone perph "
            + "inner join  perph.operator phoper where (:partnerName is null or phoper.partnerName = :partnerName) ")
    Page<Person> search(@Param("partnerName") String partnerName, Pageable pageinfo)
```

But the result is coming for all operator(Eg: if operators are AAA,BBB and CCC and I searched for AAA, all 3 results are coming in `private Set<Phone> phone`.

And also I want to use it with pageable request(for pagination).

Used `join fetch query`. It will fetch exact one but pagination will not happen with this.

So I must use only inner join to help pagination.
`Inner join` will fetch 3 objects of `Person` that in turn contains 3 elements in set(`Set<Phone> phone`).

Example:

```
Person1--[*****1, *****2, *****3]
Person1--[*****1, *****2, *****3]
Pesron1--[*****1, *****2, *****3]
```

I want 3 person object with single phone element.

```
Person1--*****1
Person1--*****2
Pesron1--*****3
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Please help me with this.

Comment: first read through: 
":partnerName is null" should be changed to "phoper.partnerName is null".

you can't have column name as parameter.

btw why do you want a null partnerName?